# IE9 input type=submit rendering border-bottom incorrectly. Fine in IE7 and 8

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-9, submit, border

I'm trying to have border-bottom only and all the other sides at 0. This seems to cause IE9 to render the border-bottom color according to the text color. Works fine in all other browsers and also previous versions of IE9.

```
#submit, #searchsubmit {
    background: #2B4C7E;
    color: #DCE0E6;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid #0E2952;
}
```

border-bottom renders correctly in IE9 if I delete `border: 0;`, but other borders will show up.

http://jsfiddle.net/56exW/

Comment: Changing `border: 0;` to `border: 0 #0E2952;` seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
border-style: solid;
border-color:#0E2952;
border-width:0 0 0.5em 0;
```